# Algorithmic classification

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to classify the following problem:

> I have N empty boxes (n<sub>i</sub> is the volume of the i-th box, 1 <= i <= N) and M divisible items (m<sub>j</sub> is the volume of j-th item j, 1 <= j <= M). The total volume of all boxes is exactly equal to the total volume of all items. I need to find a distribution of items among boxes which minimizes the number of item divisions.

I suppose this problem is NP-complete, and is some kind of set coverage problem, but I can't find appropriate variation of it.

Comment: +1 for figuring out you need to leetspell problem. That said, you should include in your question what you have attempted, and where you got stuck.

Comment: -1 figuring out you need to leetspell problem instead of typing a better title.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but doesn't this belong in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Ricky is right, this is not a question about implementation or programming.

Comment: Well, the "problem" word has several meanings... I suppose that "problem" as "trouble" is prohibited in titles, but I used it in different, scientific meaning. Anyway, I just want to know is there a well-known algorithmic problem with isomorphic description or it's just a nameless one.

Comment: Ok, I'll move it to another topic. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computimg theory and so should be on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The special case `N=2 and n_1 = n_2` is exactly the Subset Sum problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

since the optimum value of the problem formulated above is 0 if and only if
the instance (viewed as an instance of Subset Sum) has a solution. Hence, the presented problem is indeed NP-hard.